# Can I use both racks at the same time to bake chicken wings?

Tags: baking, oven, catering

Can I use my oven's top and bottom racks at the same time to bake chicken wings? I have a large party to cook for.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can! Make sure to check the wings occasionally to see if the pans need to be switched to ensure even cooking. One of the racks may get hotter than the other.
You can also make sure that both of the pans are placed as close to the center of the oven as possible by adjusting the rack positions.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you have enough space between your shelves there's no problem cooking chicken pieces on 2 layers. Some tips:

1. Make sure you have enough space around the trays as well so air can circulate, if you don't you'll get uneven cooking
2. Use convection (fan) mode if you have it to keep the temperature even
3. The top of the oven will be hotter than the bottom, so the top shelf will cook faster than the bottom, if you want them all done at the same time start cooking your bottom row a bit before the top

Comment: In my oven, the top rack is actually not as warm as the bottom or center!

Comment: That's unusual @kayk, then start the top ahead of the bottom.

Comment: Rotating the pans about half way through cooking time is probably easier than putting one in a bit early.